# Converting fractions to floating point

Tags: c, embedded, blackfin

I'm trying to convert a fraction to floating point and use it for comparison. 
but the values are too small and it returns true for the results of the Boolean variables. is my converision correct ? or should I do it in another way which I don't know ?

A test case:

```
  // result is -0.0074
  float coilh0re = fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].re)*0.8f;
  // result is -0.0092
  float coilrefundamental = fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reFundamental);
  // result is -0.01123
  float coilh0re2 = fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].re)*1.2f;
  -0.0074>-0.0092> -0.01123
```

here is a snipped of the code

```
       bool resultA  = fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].re)*0.8f < fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reFundamental)  ? 1 : 0;
       bool resultB  = fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reFundamental)  <= fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].re)*1.2f ? 1 : 0;

       bool resultAB = !(resultA & resultB); // always true

       bool resultC  =  fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[1].re)*0.8f < fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reHarmonic) ? 1:0;
       bool resultD  = fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reHarmonic)  <= fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[1].re)*1.2f ? 1:0;

       bool resultCD = !(resultC & resultD); // always true

       bool resultE  =  fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].im)*0.8f < fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imFundamental)? 1 : 0;
       bool resultF  =  fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imFundamental) <= fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].im)*1.2f ? 1 : 0;

       bool resultEF = !(resultE & resultF);// always true

       bool resultG  =  fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[1].im)*0.8f < CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imHarmonic ? 1 : 0;
       bool resultH  =  fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imHarmonic) <= fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[1].im)*1.2f ? 1 : 0;

       bool resultGH = !(resultG & resultH);// always true

        if(! ((fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].re)*0.8f < fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reFundamental)) && (fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reFundamental) <= fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].re)*1.2f) ) 
        || ! ((fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[1].re)*0.8f < fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reHarmonic))    && (fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reHarmonic) <= fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[1].re)*1.2f)    )
        || ! ((fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].im)*0.8f < fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imFundamental)) && (fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imFundamental) <= fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].im)*1.2f) )
        || ! ((fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[1].im)*0.8f < fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imHarmonic))    && (fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imHarmonic) <= fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[1].im)*1.2f)    ) )

        {
            eUserCode           = E_USER_SOIL_FAILED;
            eProcessState       = E_ERROR_HANDLING;  
        }

}
```

Comment: why negating my question ? I have provided an example with snipped code

Comment: Your "test case" contains some function calls to some unknown function using arguments that we have no idea about. It's like asking: Why doesn't this code work: `x = foo(bar)`?

Comment: **Always** prefer `double` when dealing with floating point numbers -- **never** `float` (and very very seldom `long double`).

Comment: @pmg I don't have a function that converts a fract32 to double

Comment: @pmg Context matters. Some would say the exact opposite.

Comment: Considering the previous questions you posted the last days, it looks as if this project is too challenging for your current knowledge. Instead of using us to do your job, why not get the fundamentals yourself first? Re the code: if you permanently convert float to frac and back, it would be easier and like faster to use float throughout your code. The reason to use fractional is typically **to avoid** using float.

Comment: @pmg: Depending on the necessary precision, `float` is sufficient. Especially on embedded systems (these often use the same representation for both types).

Comment: @Olaf The problem that I have the data as fractional and I want to compare, multiply them by constants, how would I multiply a fract32 with 1.2, and the fract32 range is -1,1. That's the problem

Comment: @Andre: That's what  mean with "you have to learn". No offence, but asking about **particular** problems in a very specific way will result in catastrophic results (from a performance and maintenance view). How about first learning about fractional arithmetic? There are very well ways to multiply a frac with an integer. For instance: `1.2 = (1 + 0.2)`.

Comment: @Olaf so to multiply for example 0.8 by a fraction like that fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].re)*0.8f.  I would do mult_fr1x32x32( GO_coil_H[0].re, 0.2f)

Comment: You need to go review the c operators and their precedence.  Do you understand the difference between the `&` and `&&` operators?  Do you know whether `<` takes precedence over `?`.  And is `? 1 : 0` really necessary?

Comment: @Olaf Thanks . I used your method ( 1 + 0.2) which is value + 0.2*value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If appears OP wants to test if a value `reFundamental` is in range +/-20% of `re`.  This is not a `float` precision issue, but a math one.

```
// Simplified problem
float re = -0.01123f/1.2f;
float reFundamental = -0.0092f;
bool resultA  = re*0.8f < reFundamental;
bool resultB  = reFundamental <= re*1.2f;
bool resultAB = !(resultA & resultB); // always true
```

But the values are negative and so the `<` and `<=` should be **reversed**.

Various alternatives.  Example:  (Adjust to taste)

```
bool in_range(float x, float limit, float factor) {
  float limitp = limit*(1.0f + factor);
  float limitm = limit*(1.0f - factor);

  if (x > limitm) return x <= limitp;
  if (x < limitm) return x >= limitp;
  return x == limitp;
}

bool resultAB = !in_range(fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.reFundamental),   
    fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].re), 0.20);
```

Comment: @did you forget to put 1.0f instead of 1.0d ?

Comment: @Andre Code fixed.

Comment: would you comment it a little bit, I still didn't get the logic. so you get the upper limit and the lower limit of the factor, and then what do you do ?

Comment: @Andre  `limitp` and `limitm` are not the upper limit and the lower limit.  `limitm` is the smaller in magnitude limit (closer to 0.0) and `limitp` is the greater in magnitude one.  If `x>limitm`, then `x <= limitp` is 1 or 0 corresponding to if `x` is between  `limitp` and `limitm` or not.  If `x<limitm`, then a different test is done: `x >= limitp` .

Comment: It is completely nonsense to convert back and forth between `float` and fraction. I wounder why OP uses a Fixed-point DSP if he uses (software) float anyway. An ARM Cortex-M4F would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare fractions - do not use floating-point at all. Convert them to the same denominator and compare numerators.

Comment: can you provide an example ? I didn't get how to convert them to the same denominator ?

Comment: easiest would be to multiply fraction a with the denominator of b and vice-versa. This gives common denominators. You can then compare the numerators.

Comment: @Andre [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Comparing_fractions) should be helpful.

Comment: @merl the fract32 range is -1,1. If I want to multiply fract32 A * 1.2, I would write A*10.  Then compare A with 12 ? correct ? but A*10 would overflow the fract32

Comment: @Andre I am not familiar with your data types, this is just the concept. You should read the wiki page about comparing fractions which Serhio linked. If you don't find a better may to compare the fractions you might need to change your data type or use another temporary data type for comparison.

Comment: @merl how would I convert that sentence to common denominator fr32_to_float(GO_coil_H[0].im)*0.8f < fr32_to_float(CoilEepromData.coilboardhspule.imFundamental)

Comment: a * 0.8f < b should be equal to ((a * 4) / 5) < b so you can compare 4 * a < 5 * b